# Add Mime Boundary

Tags: xslt, mime

I have an XML document to which i need to add below Mime Boundary.
Can someone please let me know how we can do this in XSL.
Please note that the Mime Boundary is always going to be static and there won't be any attachments in XML. We just need the boundaries around the XML

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/Related; type="text/xml"; boundary=_MIME-Boundary
--_MIME-Boundary
content-type: text/xml
Content-ID: BodyPart
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
<My XML Goes here>.....
--_MIME-Boundary--
```

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't this be added by a web server or another application? It's not related to XML/XSLT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:text>MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/Related; type="text/xml"; boundary=_MIME-Boundary
--_MIME-Boundary
content-type: text/xml
Content-ID: BodyPart
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
</xsl:text>
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
<xsl:text>
--_MIME-Boundary--</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that the encoding applied by the XSLT may not match the MIME declaration.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly nothing you should **ever** do, but...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>


  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>MIME-Version: 1.0&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>Content-Type: multipart/Related; type="text/xml"; boundary=_MIME-Boundary&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>--_MIME-Boundary&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>content-type: text/xml&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>Content-ID: BodyPart&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    <xsl:text>&#xa;--_MIME-Boundary--&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that a XML declaration is added manually using `disable-output-escaping`.